# Root Apt Upgrade "Permission denied" on Digital Ocean

Tags: apt, upgrade, permissions, mysql

When I run the following command 'sudo apt upgrade' as root, I get the following error on Digital Ocean.

What's wrong?

```
Removing mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--remove):
 cannot remove '/usr/bin/mysqld_safe': Permission denied
Removing mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package mysql-client-5.7 (--remove):
 cannot remove '/usr/bin/mysqlrepair': Permission denied
Removing mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package mysql-client-core-5.7 (--remove):
 cannot remove '/usr/bin/mysql': Permission denied
Removing mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-core-5.7 (--remove):
 cannot remove '/usr/bin/innochecksum': Permission denied
```

Comment: Is your root filesystem mounted read-only?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? How did you install it? Did you upgrade the OS before with no errors?

Comment: Description: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS, I didn't upgrade. I have been using the same version on Digital Ocean since 2018. Now after resetting root password, it happened like this.

Comment: How did you reset the root password?

Comment: @JoKeR from Digital Ocean dashboard

Comment: run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and then `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: @JoKeR I got this error, dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/bsdutils_1%3a2.27.1-6ubuntu3.10_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create '/usr/bin/logger.dpkg-new' (while processing './usr/bin/logger'): Permission denied
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/bsdutils_1%3a2.27.1-6ubuntu3.10_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: reboot the system and then try to repeat it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119543/discussion-between-moeseth-and-joker).